# How can I have a grid of messages, where each message shrinks to fit its container

Tags: javascript, css

I'm creating a message wall that gets updated dynamically using JS.

The wall is made up of a 'grid' of 12 absolutely positioned divs. Inside each div is some text.

Each div has a fixed width and height. There is also one parent container div which has a fixed width and height.

The message wall will be displayed on a large wall mounted TV with a fixed ratio of 16:9, and so it doesn't need to be responsive (in terms of resizing the browser).

The problem I'm having is with getting each message text to resize in order to fit within its div. I'm trying to avoid any text overflowing.

I've tried some JS solutions including https://github.com/rikschennink/fitty and http://fittextjs.com/ but these only seem to resize the text horizontally (in other words, they don't allow the text to wrap within its div.

I've included a mockup of what i'm trying to accomplish below.

[image]

Comment: Do you have an upper and a lower bound on font-size or will anything do (down to 1px?). And is each message pure text (no HTML extras in there?)

Comment: No bound on font size and each message is pure text 

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?  Why do you need JS for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea, simplistic but it seems to work.

Put the string into a fixed width div at font size 1 and see if it has height < your fixed height. If so, increase the font size and see if it fits.

If it stops fitting, decrease the font size by 1 and set the height to fixed height.

It's not efficient, but I'm guessing you won't have hundreds of messages and you won't be updating them every microsecond.

```js
const fixedWidth = 300;// set these to the fixed height and width of each text box
const fixedHeight = 200;// - in px for now but with a bit of calculation could be in %
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.fit');
divs.forEach(function(div) {
  div.style.width = fixedWidth + 'px';
  div.style.height = 'auto';
  let str = div.innerHTML; //we know it's only text
  let fontSize = 1; // bit ridiculous but need to start somewhere
  div.style.fontSize = fontSize + 'px';
  while (div.offsetHeight < fixedHeight) {
    fontSize++;
    div.style.fontSize = fontSize + 'px';
  }
  if (fontSize <= 0) {alert("Help! I just can't fit your message in. The message is: " + str);}
  else {
    div.style.fontSize = (fontSize - 1) + 'px';
    div.style.height = fixedHeight + 'px';
  }
});
```

```css
.fit {
  height: auto;
  white-space: normal;
  border: solid 2px black;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
<div class="fit">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
<div class="fit">Hello</div>
```